# Different ASP.NET Core CORS middleware behavior between development and production

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, identityserver4

I have inherited an Identity service, which is based on Identity Server. I keep getting errors about a resource (`/.well-known/openid-configuration`) because of the CORS policy, more precisely because the request is a Simple Request whose response (200 OK) does not contain a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

The overall architecture is

- a React front-end, served at https://example.com
- a set of services, each at https://example.com/ServiceName
- the identity service, at https://example.com/Identity

After several attempts based on articles and SO questions (correct order of `UseCors()` in relation to `UseRouting()`, `UseAuthentication()`, `UseHttpsRedirect()`, `UseHttpResponseCompression()`, configuration of `AddIdentityServer()`...), I tried to launch the identity service locally and noticed a different behavior compared to the one in production. If I request the OpenID Configuration directly, the production server responds with 5 headers, none of which is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, and there is a `Request-Context` header; the local server (same code) responds with 5 headers, but there is the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and the `Request-Context` one is missing.

The missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is exactly what's causing the CORS error in the browser. What can I do to ensure it is served? What other checks could I do?

EXTRA INFO:

- All services (and the front-end too) are deployed on a Kubernetes cluster that is hosted on premises at our facility.
- All services are written in .Net 5.
- Identity Server 4 is already configured to use our custom CORS policy on the discovery paths.